# Independent random variables and expected values

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, independence

I have two independent random variables $X:\Omega \rightarrow E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega \rightarrow F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ . I'd like to know why this equality is correct.

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ X - \mathbb{E}[X] \right] \, \mathbb{E} \left[ Y - \mathbb{E}[Y] \right] = 0
$$

Comment: $$
\mathsf{E}[X-\mathsf{E}X]=\mathsf{E}X-\mathsf{E}X=0.
$$

Comment: Hello @d.k.o. thank you very much